# Prevent swiping when no contents at the end

Tags: swiper.js

I am using "swiper.js" for swiping my contents.

When there are no content at the end if I try to swipe it,blank space is coming and after releasing mouse it comes it's actual position.it's not a bug.but I still want to prevent such swipe if there are no more slide.I tried using API docs of swiper.js.but could not resolve the issue.

Could any one please help me?thanks in advance.

Comment: I tried to read the code you posted, but couldn't find it.

Comment: If i pull right/left when no more contents at the end .one blanks space comes.u want to prevent that.stop swiping when contents ends

Comment: That does not address the main glaring issue with this question that I brought up earlier.

Comment: If this is a bug report, you should file it with the guys who wrote swiper.js.

Comment: It's not a bug .i just want to prevent such swiping

Comment: Sounds like a feature enhancement then. Still goes to the same place. Not here.